# Carrierwave / Fog to S3 fails with files over 5mb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I have a Rails 4 app that uses Carrierwave and Fog to upload files to Amazon S3. The servers the app uses is Nginx and Thin.

The problem I'm having is when uploading files over 5mb.

I've tried searching everywhere for a way to get it working, I've tried CarrierwaveDirect and still can't get it to work.

Here is my Carrierwave config:

```
config.fog_directory  = 'aws-bucket-name'
config.fog_public     = false
config.fog_attributes = { multipart_chunk_size: 5242880 }
config.max_file_size = 200.megabytes # CarrierwaveDirect option
```

Here are the controller actions:

```
def new
  @file = DownloadFile.new
end

def create
  @file = DownloadFile.new
  @file.file = params[:download_file][:file]

  if @file.save
    redirect_to downloads_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

And the form:

```
<%= form_for @file, multipart: true do |f| %> <!-- even tried with `multipart` wrapped in `html: {}` -->
  <%= f.label :file %>
  <%= f.file_field :file %>
  <%= f.button t(:upload) %>
<% end %>
```

I can upload small files just fine, but when it comes to files that are over 5mb, the form just redisplays. No errors, no errors in the logs, nothing.

Comment: show your controller action and view form.

Comment: Done. I'm searching for what may be causing this and it's either a timeout thing somewhere or for some reason AWS S3 doesn't want to take files larger than 5mb.

Comment: I've narrowed is done to files larger than 5mb and Carrierwave. When I upload using only Fog, it works, but when Carrierwave is in the mix it completely fails. It's like it doesn't how how to tell Fog to do a multipart upload.

Answer (score 0):

With Carrierwave Direct it looks like you would need to setup the form slightly differently (as it would need to set the url to one on S3, rather than on your own server). If you are dealing with large files this may be preferable as large files would otherwise tie up a process for an extended time. To make that work it looks like you'll want to use the `direct_upload_form_for` helper method instead of plain `form_for`, something like:

```
<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

For a bit more detail on that, see: https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct#rails

Comment: Yes and I have tried this, but like I said, when I tried it, I still couldn't upload files larger than 5mb.